# How use flalign to align the equations on the left?

Tags: equations, align, vertical-alignment, paragraphs

I am writing some algebra notes and unfortunately I have some problem with the alignment of some equation: exactly the equation appears aligned on the right whereas I would like they are aligned on the left as showed into this image which is form a paper written in a doc. format.

[image]

So I wrote this code hoping I would obtained a text as into the image above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[flneq]{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textwidth=17cm,textheight=25 cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}

\setcounter{equation}{-1}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\setcounter{lemma}{-1}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposizione}
\setcounter{proposition}{-1}

\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollario}
\setcounter{corollary}{-1}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\setcounter{theorem}{-1}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x_{i\big(\sigma(0)\big)}\bot\dots\bot x_{i\big(\sigma(m)\big)}\bot x_{i\big(\sigma(m+1)\big)}=\\
    x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(0)\big)\Big)}\bot x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(1)\big)\Big)}\bot\dots\bot x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m)\big)\Big)}\bot x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m+1)\big)\Big)}=\\
    x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(0)\big)\Big)}\bot\biggl(x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(1)\big)\Big)}\bot\dots\bot x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m)\big)\Big)}\bot x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m+1)\big)\Big)}\biggl)=\\
    x_{i\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(0)\big)}\bot\biggl(x_{i\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(1)\big)}\bot\dots\bot x_{i\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m)\big)}\bot x_{i\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m+1)\big)}\biggl)=\\
    \biggl(x_{i\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(0)\big)}\bot x_{i\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(1)\big)}\bot\dots\bot x_{i\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m)\big)}\biggl)\bot x_{i\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m+1)\big)}=\\
    (x_{i(0)}\bot x_{i(1)}\bot\dots\bot x_{i(m)})\bot x_{i(m+1)}=\\
    x_{i(0)}\bot\dots\bot x_{i(m)}\bot x_{i(m+1)}
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

but unfortunately the out put is just this

[image]

which is really different. So, how to obtain a text as into the first image? I point out I proved to use `\flalign` command but it does not work.

Comment: Your equation contains typo(s) and does not compile as such at the moment.

Comment: @Karlo I find only two tipos which I corrected: unfortunately nothing is changed. [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4669/736008) you can see that the latex equation work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this construction:

```
\[ \begin{aligned}
     & x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(0)\big)\Big)}\bot x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(1)\big)\Big)}\bot\dots\bot x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m)\big)\Big)}\bot x_{i\Big(\psi_\sigma^{m+1}\big(\varphi_\sigma^{m+1}(m+1)\big)\Big)}=\\
     & x_{i\big(\sigma(0)\big)}\bot\dots\bot x_{i\big(\sigma(m)\big)}\bot x_{i\big(\sigma(m+1)\big)}=\\
\end{aligned} \]
```

which gives

[image]

The `&` sign defines the alignment at the left hand side.

Comment: Okay, so I have to put the symbol & at the beginning of any line, right?

Comment: Yes, you'll see what happens if you forget to put it on one line!

Comment: Okay: it works perfectly so that I upvoted and accepted your answer. Thanks very much for your assistance! :-)

Comment: Only one last question: if I want tag the equation then do I have use \equation and & still works?

Comment: Indeed: you can use `\begin{equation}` to have a numbered equation, instead of `\[` or `\begin{equation*}` for an unnumbered one.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information!!! :-)